# Displaying (different) number of Plots with same axis

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series

I have a simple list containing a varying number of columns. In this case I have a time axis and four data points for each time:

```
time <- seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=N+1)
lst <- list(time, Y, X1, X2, X3)
```

I am looking for a way to plot these data sets with the same time axis, but in different plots (stacked). My problem is that I don't know how many data sets, e.g. plots, I will have in before.

Is there an elegant way to handle this?
Thanks in advance.

PS: I had a look at the R package `lattice`, but it won't work with my list setup. If anyone knows how to change the data type properly I would be very thankful.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: You should also check out the R equisse package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/esquisse/versions/1.0.1 which has a chart wizard UI for drag and drop construction of ggplots.  ggplot code is also generated than can be copied and pasted for further refinement.

Comment: Questions to SO should have complete input and shown using `dput`.  See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your data, it's difficult to provide a specific solution. Here I have outlined two strategies that you might use.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

# Solution 1: List of plots using ggarrange
time <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100)

lst = list(
  X = rnorm(100),
  Y = rnorm(100),
  Z = rnorm(100)
)

# Take our list of data and return a list of plots
plot_list = lapply(lst, function(x) {
  data = data.frame(time = time, var = x)
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = var)) +
    geom_point()
})

ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list)
```

[image]

```r
# Solution 2: Facetting using long data

lst2 = lst = list(
  time = time,
  X = rnorm(100),
  Y = rnorm(100),
  Z = rnorm(100)
)

# Combine all list elements, ASSUMING equal length
all_data = bind_rows(lst2)

# Make it long form for facetting
all_data = all_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(time))

# Facetted plot
ggplot(all_data, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This looks nice, but how is it possible to stack them vertically and only have one time axis?

Comment: Can you elaborate? You can change the number of rows and columns, but is that what you mean? Or do you want to have only one plot with multiple lines?

Comment: Sorry if i haven't been clear.. basically, I would like to have a plot like your second example, but with a shared x-axis and not a shared y-axis.

Comment: You only need to specify `scales = "free_y` to accomplish that, then you will have a plot like the ones above with shared x but individual y axis.